# PerformClick() for a radio button not working

Tags: c#

There is a usercontrol which has a radio button and that user control is called in a dialog box. I have written an `onclick` event for radio button and used `performclick()` to call it. But even though `performclick()` is being executed without any exception, it's not performing on click action.
 It's neither calling on click function nor reflecting a check in UI. But the on-click event works perfectly if I click it manually in the UI.

I am using VS2010 and to test the case I created a helloworld project. I observed the app worked well when the `Causesvalidation` property of radiobutton is false, but doesn't when that validation property is true.

How can I fix this?

More: As I researched more I found out that Performclick doesn't work well when controls are called inside other controls and when this is done for many layers. It was same in my case, there were four layers to reach my radiobutton. So I replaced the prformclick function by calling onclick function directly and then making radiobutton.checked = true inside that function.

Comment: Code belongs to the company I work for, so I didn't put it.

Comment: In such a case, obfuscate your code and post it. People tend to answer questions with some code more than questions without it because they can try it themselfs and see what is working for them.

Comment: sure. I will do it henceforth. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `radioButton.PerformClick();`:

If the radio button is checked only the `radioButton.Click` - Event will fire

If the radio button is not checked the `radioButton.Click` & `radioButton.CheckedChange` - Event will fire so make sure you use the right Event

Hope this is helpful